# padding issue in Firefox

Tags: css, padding

http://www.pcdconsultancy.co.uk/

Im having trouble with my menu. It appears to have at least a couple of pixels bigger on Firefox than IE or chrome, can someone advise me what the appears to be? ive tried to tweak it but it seems to still be out.

My menu css is :

```
#headermenu { margin-top: 9px; margin-left: 80px;}
#headermenu ul {background: #efefef; 
padding: 0px;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
display: inline-table;
 }
#headermenu ul li {
float: left;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #999999 0%, #3a3a3a 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#999999), color-stop(100%,#3a3a3a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #999999 0%,#3a3a3a 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #999999 0%,#3a3a3a 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #999999 0%,#3a3a3a 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #999999 0%,#3a3a3a 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#999999', endColorstr='#3a3a3a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
 border-left: 1px solid #666666;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 border-top: 1px solid #999999;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
 }
#headermenu ul li:hover {}
#headermenu ul li a {display: block; color: #fff; text-decoration: none;font: 15px Arial; padding: 7px 20px; /* Old browsers */}
```

Comment: Post your html as well.

Comment: @Cam: She provided a link to her website, that is just as good, if not even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a line-height declaration to the #headermenu ul li a element, that should fix the issue. See code below:

```
#headermenu ul li a {line-height: 15px;}
```

I guarantee that will fix your issue.

Thank you!